# What factors are considered in automatic brightness adjustment?

Tags: windows-8

When I set monitor brightness adjustment to automatic (`adaptive brightness`), my brightness never changes.

It is always locked at the highest brightness.

What factors are considered for automatic brightness adjustment?
(certainly they are not using my camera...)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Adaptive brightness is a feature in Windows that uses a light sensor
> to automatically adjust the display brightness to match the lighting
> conditions in your computer's surroundings. To use adaptive
> brightness, you must have light sensors installed and enabled on your
> computer.

It seems to use its own Ambient Light sensor (ALS) if present. If not present, I guess it **wouldn't dim the display at all**. Usually the light sensors have very few levels of light detection (in **lux**). It has been around since Windows 7.

(**[More](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/sensorslocation/overview-of-adaptive-brightness-in-windows-7)**)

Answer (score 0):

As Cthulhu said, it used the Ambient Light Sensor, which you probably don't have if you aren't seeing any brightness changes.  I would suggest using a program to control this, such as [F.lux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/).  You can let it run on defaults or configure to your specific usage.  It takes a bit to get used to, but it really helps on eye strain (at least for me it did).